# my view in asp.net mvc crashed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, tfs

I use Visual Studio 2013 with ASP.NET MVC 5 and TFS when I run project
my PC turns off.

When I run VS again my one view that is not in TFS gives me an error, it was working fine before my PC turned off.

**Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message**:

> CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

Source Error:

> Line 51: BeginContext("~/Views/ATM/CreateExecl.cshtml", 0, 4434, true);
>
> Line 52:
>
> Line 53: WriteLiteral("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +

and view in project like : -

```
000000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...............

000000010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...............
```

Comment: what's the code in the view? are you saying that compiling/running the project or displaying the view causes your PC to crash?

Comment: my PC turn off when running the project   Because electricity , my question is why view lost code and seem like binary code ???

Comment: file must have become corrupted - sudden unexpected shutdowns can cause that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file probably became corrupted due to the power outage. You'll need to rewrite your view since it sounds like you didn't yet have it checked into source code control.

In order to avoid this in the future, it's wise to have your computer on an [Uninterruptible Power Supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply). These are basically large batteries you plug your PC and monitor and other essential equipment into that give you some time to save your work and perform a proper shut down in the event of a power outage, or allow you to keep working through brief power outages.